# T-SQL Index Of First Character In a String

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, character, indexof

How can I find the index of the first numeric character in a string using T-SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx):

```
select patindex('%[0-9]%', 'My1String')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'your_12345_string')
```

See [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/2522)